# Pegar valor do radio button selecionado e iniciar o IF, ELSE IF, ELSE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao carregar a página, preciso verificar qual radio button está selecionado. Depois iniciar o `IF, ELSE IF, ELSE`.

**html**

```
  <input type="radio" name="situacao" id="situacao_reserva" value="R" /> Reserva

  <input type="radio" name="situacao" id="situacao_saida" value="S" checked />Saida

  <input type="radio" name="situacao" id="situacao_chegada" value="C" />Retornou
```

**JS**

```
$("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "S") {

    $("#data_ini").attr("readonly", true);
    $("#data_ini").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $('#tab-kmUsado').css('display', 'none');

  } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {

    $("#data_fim").attr("readonly", true);
    $("#data_fim").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("#data_fim").val(str_data + " " + str_hora);

  } else {

  }
}).change();
```

Ao carregar a página, o `radio saída`, já aparece desativado, sedo que ele deveria desativar apenas quando for clicado no `radio retornou`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar o trigger `.change()` o evento irá percorrer todos os 3 radios, e isso não vai funcionar corretamente porque vai entrar em todos os if's.

O que você precisa fazer é apenas adicionar os métodos `.parent()`e `.find()` antes do `.change()` para buscar apenas o radio checado:

```
$("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {

   if ($(this).val() == "S") {

      $("#data_ini").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_ini").attr("disabled", true);

   } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {

      $("#data_fim").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_fim").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#data_fim").val(str_data + " " + str_hora);

   } else {

   }
}).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();
```

O `.parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked")` vai buscar apenas o radio checado no elemento pai disparar o `.change()`.

**Teste:**

```js
// valores apenas para exemplo
str_data = "02/04/2019";
str_hora = "10:00";

$("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {

   if ($(this).val() == "S") {

      console.log("S");
      $("#data_ini").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_ini").attr("disabled", true);

   } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {

      console.log("C");
      $("#data_fim").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_fim").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#data_fim").val(str_data + " " + str_hora);

   } else {

      console.log("R");

   }
}).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="data_ini"> data_ini
<br>
<input id="data_fim"> data_fim
<br>
<input type="radio" name="situacao" id="situacao_reserva" value="R" /> Reserva
<br>
<input type="radio" name="situacao" id="situacao_saida" value="S" checked />Saida
<br>
<input type="radio" name="situacao" id="situacao_chegada" value="C" />Retornou
```

Comment: San, adicionei `$('#tab-kmUsado').css('display', 'none');`, mas não esta sendo executado quando a página é carregada, apenas quando o click no radio é feito. Porque isso?

Comment: Tente `$('#tab-kmUsado').hide();`

Comment: Tambem não deu.

Comment: Só funciona, quando eu mudo a seleção do radio.

Comment: Blz, muito obrigado.

Comment: Arrumei, mas use `$('#tab-kmUsado').hide();` em vez de `$('#tab-kmUsado').css('display', 'none');`, que é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Deu cero! Obrigado.

Comment: Sam, como faço para chamar essa esse comando `$(".c").on('change', function(e) {` dentro do `else if ($(this).val() == "C")`.

Comment: Cara, eu tô na rua. Posso ver isso depois pra vc

Comment: Blz, criei outro post para ficar melhor o entendimento. Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373115/chamar-evento-dentro-de-outro-evento-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um `document.getElementById` para pegar o valor dos três, remover o value dos inputs e então fazer o seguinte:

```
//botão para enviar o valor do radio
<input type="submit" value="enviar" onclick="exemplo();">

function exemplo(){
var reserva = document.getElementById("situacao_reserva").value;
var saida = document.getElementById("situacao_saida").value;
var chegada = document.getElementById(""situacao_chegada").value;

if(reserva==true)
{  
    //insira o código
}
elseif(saida==true)
{
    $("#data_ini").attr("readonly", true);
    $("#data_ini").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
elseif(chegada==true)
{
    $("#data_fim").attr("readonly", true);
    $("#data_fim").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#data_fim").val(str_data + " " + str_hora);    
}
}
```

Caso meu código não ajude, provavelmente o problema do código já aparecer desativado, é porque você colocou um `else`. No momento em que essa função rodar, vai cair no `else` toda a hora

Answer (score 1):

Nas condições em vez de `$(this).val()` para pegar os valores use 
`$("input[name=situacao]:checked").val()`

[Sobre](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)