# Chamar evento dentro de outro evento jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de chamar um evento dentro de outro evento..

Seria o **Evento B** dentro do `else if ($(this).val() == "C")`, do **Evento A**

**CÓDIGO COMPLETO:** https://jsfiddle.net/yswdr7on/

**Evento A:**

```
$("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "S") {
     //
     //

  } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {

     $(".c").on(); //Não funciona.
     $(".recalcula").click(); //Esse funciona.

  } else {
     //
     //

  }
}).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();
```

**Evento B:**

```
$(".c").on('change', function(e) {

  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

    //
    //
    //

  } else if (e.bubbles) {

    //
    //
    //
  }
  $(".recalcula").click();
}).change();
```

Comment: Mas `$(".c").on(` o quê? `.c` é uma classe?

Comment: Olá, sim, como o código é muito grande achei melhor não colocar para ficar mais limpo a tela. Coloquei nesse link para melhor visualização https://jsfiddle.net/yswdr7on/

Comment: @Sam Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: @Sam Tambem não funciona...rsrs

Comment: Tenta `$(".c").trigger("change")`

Comment: @Sam deu certo, mas não como imaginava. Vou ter que refazer meu codigo aqui...rsrs Obrigado Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para chamar o evento `change` em `$(".c").on('change', function(e) {...` você usa o método [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) do jQuery:

```
$(".c").trigger("change");
```

Agora, como `.c` é uma classe, irá disparar o evento o número de vezes igual a quantidade de elementos com a classe `.c`.

Comment: Sam, veja se consegue me ajudar com esse problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373505/recalcular-ao-alterar-data-ou-clicar-no-radio-button

Answer (score 0):

Oi, esta faltando um `if()` no seu código B.

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "S") {
            } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {
                $(".c").on('change keydown paste input', function(e) {
                    if (true) {
                    } else if (e.bubbles) {
                    }
                    $(".recalcula").click();
                });
                $(".recalcula").click();
            } else {
            }
        }).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="situacao" value="C">
<input type="text" class="c">
<input class="recalcula" type="button" value="Recalcula" onclick="console.log('RECALCULA...');">
```

Se você quiser que ocorra um evento a cada click coloque `keydown` ao pressionar a tecla, `paste` ao colar, `input` ao modificar.

Comment: Coloquei o `IF`

Comment: Como sugeriu não funcionou.