# Recalcular ao alterar data ou clicar no radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Olá,
Como fazer para recalcular os valores **TAXAS E SERVIÇOS** e o **SOMA DAS TAXAS E SERVIÇOS** ao fazer a alteração do campo `dataFim` ou se for clicado no `radio button = situacao_chegada`.

Agradeço a todos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data = new Date();
  var dia = ("0" + data.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var mes = ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var ano4 = data.getFullYear();
  var hora = ("0" + data.getHours()).slice(-2);
  var min = ("0" + data.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  var str_data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano4;
  var str_hora = hora + ':' + min;




  $("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "S") {
      $("#data_ini").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_ini").attr("disabled", true);

      $('#tab-kmUsado').hide();

    } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {
      $("#data_fim").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_fim").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#data_fim").val(str_data + " " + str_hora);
      $("#tab_cliente").mouseover();
      $('#tab-avisoKmUsado').hide();
      $('#tab-kmUsado').show();


      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KL") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val());
        planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KMC") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria_controlada").val());
        planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria_controlada").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "DI") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria").val());
        planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroCarro']:checked").val() == "S") {
        $("#SegCarroS2").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#SegCarroS3").html($("#val_seguro_carro").val());
        seguroV = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_carro").val();
        $("#SegCarroS4").html(seguroV.toFixed(2));
        $(".SegCarroS4").val(seguroV.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#SegCarroS2").html("0");
        $("#SegCarroS3").html("0");
        $("#SegCarroS4").html("0.00");
        $(".SegCarroS4").val("0.00");
      }

      if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroTerceiros']:checked").val() == "S") {
        $("#SegTerceirosT2").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#SegTerceirosT3").html($("#val_seguro_terceiros").val());
        seguroT = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_terceiros").val();
        $("#SegTerceirosT4").html(seguroT.toFixed(2));
        $(".SegTerceirosT4").val(seguroT.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#SegTerceirosT2").html("0");
        $("#SegTerceirosT3").html("0");
        $("#SegTerceirosT4").html("0.00");
        $(".SegTerceirosT4").val("0.00");
      }


      $(".recalcula").click();

    } else {

    }
  }).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();





  $("#tab_cliente").on('mouseover', function() {
    DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var data_ini = $("#data_ini").val().toString().split('/');
    data_ini2 = data_ini[1] + "/" + data_ini[0] + "/" + data_ini[2];
    d1 = new Date(data_ini2);

    var data_fim = $("#data_fim").val().toString().split('/');
    data_fim2 = data_fim[1] + "/" + data_fim[0] + "/" + data_fim[2];
    d2 = new Date(data_fim2);

    $("#data_ini2").val($("#data_ini").val());

    var diasLocacao = Math.round((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DAY);

    $("#dias").val(diasLocacao);


  }).mouseover();





  $(".c").on('change', function() {

    var values = $(this).val().split('|');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

      var quantity = $("table[id^=tabelaIE]").length;

      $(this).data('qty', quantity);

      var table = $("#tabelaIE").clone(true)
        .attr('id', function() {
          return this.id + quantity;
        })
        .find(':text,:file')
        .attr('id', function() {
          return this.id + quantity;
        })
        .val("")
        .end();

      //VALUE -> 1|Taxa de locação|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%
      //$ID_ImpEnc|$nome|$tipo|$valor|$calculo|$valor_em|$aplicacao|$a

      //APLICAÇÃO: [SEG] Sobre seguro, [KML] KmLivre, [DIA] Diária, [IE] Impostos/Encargos, [VLT] no valor total
      //VALOR EM.: [MOT] Montante, [POR] Porcentagem.
      //CALCULO..: [DIA]Por dia, [FIX]Fixo
      //TIPO.....: [TXV]Taxa de Venda, [ENC]Encargos Extras

      aplicacao = values[6];
      valor_em = values[5];
      calculo = values[4];
      tipo = values[2];

      if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "FIX") {
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text("1");
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * 1;
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "DIA") {
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if (valor_em == "POR" && calculo == "FIX") {
        if (aplicacao == "SEG") {
          $V = (50 + 30) / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "KML") {
          $V = values[3] / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] - $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "DIA") {
          $V = (values[3] * $("#dias").val()) / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "VLT") {
          $V = $("#totalFatura").val() / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3].substring(0, 2) + "%");
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
      }



      values.forEach(function(valor, index) {
        table.find('[class="split' + (index + 1) + '"]').val(valor)
      });

      table.appendTo('#abc');

      var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
      $('#somaTabelaIE').val(eval(oldVal || 0) + eval(tTotal));

    } else {

      tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
      var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
      $('#somaTabelaIE').val(oldVal - eval(tTotal));

      //remove a table que pertence ao checkbox
      $("table#tabelaIE" + $(this).data('qty')).remove();
    }
    $(".recalcula").click();
  }).change();




});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab_cliente"></div>
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_reserva" value="R" disabled /> Reserva
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_saida" value="S" checked />Saída
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_chegada" value="C" />Chegada

<p>
  dataIni: <input name="dataIni" type="text" id="data_ini" value="01/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  dataFim: <input name="dataFim" type="text" id="data_fim" value="03/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  Dias: <input type="text" id="dias" style="width: 50px">
</p>

<p>===============================================</p>
Total fatura: <input type="text" id="totalFatura" value="100.00" />
<p>===============================================</p>

<strong>OPTIONS:</strong>
<div id="D1">1.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c Obrig" type="checkbox" checked value="1|Taxa aluguel|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%" alt="15.00" title="Rental Rate" /> <b> Taxa aluguel </b>
</div>
<div id="D2">2.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="2|GPS|ENC|5.00|DIA|MON|DIA|" alt="5.00" title="GPS" /> GPS
</div>
<div id="D3">3.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Lavagem carro|ENC|30.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="30.00" title="Car wash" /> Lavagem carro
</div>
<div id="D4">4.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="4|Transfer|ENC|35.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="35.00" title="Transfer" /> Transfer
</div>


<p>===============================================</p>
<table width="400" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><b>TAXAS E SERVIÇOS</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="abc">
        <table id="tabelaIE" width='400' border='0'>
          <tr>
            <td class="tNome" width='190px'></td>
            <td class="tDias" width='50px' align='center'></td>
            <td class="tValor" width='60px' align='right'></td>
            <td class="tTotal" width='100px' align='right'></td>
            <td class="tValores">
              <input type="hidden" class="split1" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split2" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split3" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split4" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split5" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split6" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split7" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split8" value="">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>===============================================</p>

SOMA DAS TAXAS E SERVIÇOS:
<input type="text" class="somaTabelaIE" id="somaTabelaIE" value="0">
```

Comment: Esse [listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one) deve ajudar: `document.querySelector('#situacao_chegada').addEventListener('change', () -> {//Blah});`

Comment: Os cálculos já estão funcionando?

Comment: @Sam Sim, já estão funcionando nos meus arquivos, só aqui que não funciona. Quando removo o evento `$("#tab_cliente").on('mouseover', function() {` funciona, mas isso somente aqui, nos meus arquivos funciona.

Comment: @Sam você consegue me ajudar?

Comment: @Sam, se for muito completo para ajudar, quanto você me cobraria para resolver esse problema?

Comment: qd eu chegar em casa eu vejo pra vc

Comment: Fantastico, muito obrigado @Sam

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função separada para calcular o total, não faça dentro de uma função de evento porque complica bastante. Veja que criei a função `somaTaxas()` que percorre as últimas td's da tabela e vai somando, depois joga o resultado no input de total.

Crie também um event handler `blur` e `click` nos elementos `#data_fim` e `#situacao_chegada` que chama a função de cálculo e chama os outros eventos que calculam as taxas. Veja no código abaixo o que foi adicionado e removido.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   var data = new Date();
   var dia = ("0" + data.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var mes = ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   var ano4 = data.getFullYear();
   var hora = ("0" + data.getHours()).slice(-2);
   var min = ("0" + data.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
   var str_data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano4;
   var str_hora = hora + ':' + min;

   $("#data_fim, #situacao_chegada").on("click blur", function(e){
      setTimeout(function(){
         $("#tab_cliente").mouseover();
         $('#abc table:not(:first)').remove();
         $(".c").change();
         somaTaxas();
      }, 100);
   });

   $("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {
      
      if ($(this).val() == "S") {

         $("#data_ini").attr({
            "readonly": true,
            "disabled": true
         });
   
         $('#tab-kmUsado').hide();

      } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {

         $("#data_fim").attr({
            "readonly": true,
            "disabled": true
         }).val(str_data + " " + str_hora);
         $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", false);
         $("#tab_cliente").mouseover();
         $('#tab-avisoKmUsado').hide();
         $('#tab-kmUsado').show();

      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KL") {

        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val());
        var planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KMC") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria_controlada").val());
        var planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria_controlada").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "DI") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria").val());
        var planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroCarro']:checked").val() == "S") {
        $("#SegCarroS2").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#SegCarroS3").html($("#val_seguro_carro").val());
        var seguroV = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_carro").val();
        $("#SegCarroS4").html(seguroV.toFixed(2));
        $(".SegCarroS4").val(seguroV.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#SegCarroS2, #SegCarroS3").html("0");
        $("#SegCarroS4").html("0.00");
        $(".SegCarroS4").val("0.00");
      }

      if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroTerceiros']:checked").val() == "S") {
        $("#SegTerceirosT2").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#SegTerceirosT3").html($("#val_seguro_terceiros").val());
        var seguroT = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_terceiros").val();
        $("#SegTerceirosT4").html(seguroT.toFixed(2));
        $(".SegTerceirosT4").val(seguroT.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#SegTerceirosT2, #SegTerceirosT3").html("0");
        $("#SegTerceirosT4").html("0.00");
        $(".SegTerceirosT4").val("0.00");
      }


      $(".recalcula").click();

    } else {

    }
  }).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();

  $("#tab_cliente").on('mouseover', function() {
    DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var data_ini = $("#data_ini").val().toString().split('/');
    data_ini2 = data_ini[1] + "/" + data_ini[0] + "/" + data_ini[2];
    d1 = new Date(data_ini2);

    var data_fim = $("#data_fim").val().toString().split('/');
    data_fim2 = data_fim[1] + "/" + data_fim[0] + "/" + data_fim[2];
    d2 = new Date(data_fim2);

    $("#data_ini2").val($("#data_ini").val());

    var diasLocacao = Math.round((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DAY);

    $("#dias").val(diasLocacao);

  }).mouseover();


  $(".c").on('change', function() {

   
    var values = $(this).val().split('|');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

      var quantity = $("table[id^=tabelaIE]").length;

      $(this).data('qty', quantity);

      var table = $("#tabelaIE").clone(true)
        .attr('id', function() {
          return this.id + quantity;
        })
        .find(':text,:file')
        .attr('id', function() {
          return this.id + quantity;
        })
        .val("")
        .end();

      //VALUE -> 1|Taxa de locação|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%
      //$ID_ImpEnc|$nome|$tipo|$valor|$calculo|$valor_em|$aplicacao|$a

      //APLICAÇÃO: [SEG] Sobre seguro, [KML] KmLivre, [DIA] Diária, [IE] Impostos/Encargos, [VLT] no valor total
      //VALOR EM.: [MOT] Montante, [POR] Porcentagem.
      //CALCULO..: [DIA]Por dia, [FIX]Fixo
      //TIPO.....: [TXV]Taxa de Venda, [ENC]Encargos Extras

      aplicacao = values[6];
      valor_em = values[5];
      calculo = values[4];
      tipo = values[2];

      if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "FIX") {
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text("1");
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * 1;
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "DIA") {
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if (valor_em == "POR" && calculo == "FIX") {
        if (aplicacao == "SEG") {
          $V = (50 + 30) / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "KML") {
          $V = values[3] / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] - $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "DIA") {
          $V = (values[3] * $("#dias").val()) / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "VLT") {
          $V = $("#totalFatura").val() / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3].substring(0, 2) + "%");
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
      }



//      values.forEach(function(valor, index) {
//        table.find('[class="split' + (index + 1) + '"]').val(valor)
//      });

      table.appendTo('#abc');
      //$("#data_fim, #situacao_chegada").blur();

//      var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
//      $('#somaTabelaIE').val(eval(oldVal || 0) + eval(tTotal));

    } else {

      tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
//      var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
//      $('#somaTabelaIE').val(oldVal - eval(tTotal));

      //remove a table que pertence ao checkbox
      $("table#tabelaIE" + $(this).data('qty')).remove();
    }
    $(".recalcula").click();
  }).change();

   function somaTaxas(){
      var soma = 0;
      $("#abc table:not(:first) .tTotal").each(function(){
         soma += parseFloat($(this).text());
      });
      $("#somaTabelaIE").val(soma.toFixed(2));
   }
    somaTaxas();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab_cliente"></div>
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_reserva" value="R" disabled /> Reserva
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_saida" value="S" checked />Saída
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_chegada" value="C" />Chegada

<p>
  dataIni: <input name="dataIni" type="text" id="data_ini" value="01/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  dataFim: <input name="dataFim" type="text" id="data_fim" value="04/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  Dias: <input type="text" id="dias" style="width: 50px">
</p>

<p>===============================================</p>
Total fatura: <input type="text" id="totalFatura" value="300.00" />
<p>===============================================</p>

<strong>OPTIONS:</strong>
<div id="D1">1.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c Obrig" type="checkbox" checked value="1|Taxa aluguel|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%" alt="15.00" title="Rental Rate" /> <b> Taxa aluguel </b>
</div>
<div id="D2">2.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="2|GPS|ENC|5.00|DIA|MON|DIA|" alt="5.00" title="GPS" /> GPS
</div>
<div id="D3">3.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Lavagem carro|ENC|30.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="30.00" title="Car wash" /> Lavagem carro
</div>
<div id="D4">4.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="4|Transfer|ENC|35.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="35.00" title="Transfer" /> Transfer
</div>


<p>===============================================</p>
<table width="400" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><b>TAXAS E SERVIÇOS</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="abc">
        <table id="tabelaIE" width='400' border='0'>
          <tr>
            <td class="tNome" width='190px'></td>
            <td class="tDias" width='50px' align='center'></td>
            <td class="tValor" width='60px' align='right'></td>
            <td class="tTotal" width='100px' align='right'></td>
            <td class="tValores">
              <input type="hidden" class="split1" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split2" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split3" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split4" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split5" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split6" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split7" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split8" value="">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>===============================================</p>

SOMA DAS TAXAS E SERVIÇOS:
<input type="text" class="somaTabelaIE" id="somaTabelaIE" value="0">
```

Comment: Olá Sam. Para atualizar o dia nas **TAXAS E SERVIÇOS** tem que clicar novamente na tela? Poderia ser calculado quando clicado no `radio` Chegada?

Comment: Coloquei na resposta, nessa parte `$("#data_fim, #situacao_chegada").on("blur click",`

Comment: Olá Sam, bom dia. A **TAXAS E SERVIÇOS** está sendo apenas quando tem um click na tela. Exemplo: Clico em chegada e depois tenho que clicar na tela para atualizar o GPS, que usa parâmetro de dias.

Comment: Boa tarde. Entendeu?

Comment: Acho que entendi. O evento "blur" só é disparado quando sai do campo da data. Adiciona mais um evento, "input", ficando assim: `"blur click input"`

Comment: Colocar aqui `$("#data_fim, #situacao_chegada").on("blur click", function(){`? Se for, parece que não deu não, fiz o teste e não atualizou.

Comment: Sim, junto com blur e click. Tenta adicionando mais um evento, change: `$("#data_fim, #situacao_chegada").on("blur click input change", function(){`

Comment: Não foi. Atualiza apenas quando dou um click na tela.

Comment: Sam, você tem skype?

Comment: Opa! Não tenho não :/

Comment: Gostaria de saber quanto cobraria para fazer isso para mim, não tenho dinheiro sobrando, mas sou grato por ter me ajudado até agora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92200/discussion-between-sam-and-tiago).

Comment: Sam, boa tarde. Quanto você cobra para fazer funcionar essa parte de calculo?

Comment: Eu entrei, mas esta fechado.